# Set a review date on a document in sharepoint 2010

Tags: document-library

In sharepoint 2010 I want to create a document library and be able to set a review date on the documents so that the user is informed about reviewing at the said date. I remember this was possible in 2007 but cant seem to find the option in 2010.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great walk-thru on how to set it up: http://www.abelsolutions.com/Newsroom/SharePointTOTM/Pages/TOTM20092911.aspx

Note that the "Information management policy settings" required for the trigger do not exist in SharePoint foundation, so if you are not using SharePoint 2010 Standard or Enterprise, then we'll need to find another approach.

Comment: mmm, am I right in thinking in SharePoint 2007 you could quite literally set a review date in the document properties and this would trigger an email to the document creator as and when that date is reached?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a workflow that coordinates the notification and or the review activity.  The workflow can be created in SharePoint Designer or with Visual Studio.